# What is the CSS for moving a button DOWN on a slider for the Divi Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, button, themes

This is what I have so far:

[image]

Though I'd like it to look more like this:

[image]

What is the CSS for moving a `Button` down?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! "Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example."

Answer (score 0):

If you meant changing the button position to center it vertically inside it's containing div, question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027949/3468846), use this on your button containing div :

```
    .containerDiv {
   display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kf7bcurj/2/)